# Windows batch script to list files in directory and assign to variables

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have always scripted in Unix, but now have a requirement to do something in Windows.
Requirement is that a property file contains path variable. The script needs to list all files under that path and then call a function on each file. This is what I have been trying

```
@For /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN (C:\Work\sample\myFile.properties) DO (
IF "%%A"=="MPWR_EXPORT_PATH" set MPWR_EXPORT_PATH=%%B
IF "%%A"=="FILE_SHARE" set FILE_SHARE=%%B
)
cd %MPWR_EXPORT_PATH%
FOR %%i IN (*) DO echo %%i
```

Question is:
How do I assign the %%i to variable and then pass filename to a function DISPAY()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to assign to a variable to pass it to a function. The called function receives the parameter as `%1` and it can be refined with the `%~1` syntax.

I also suggest you to change your `CD` command for a `PUSHD`. This way (1) your `%MPWR_PATH%` variable can contain a drive letter or a network path, and (2) the bat can later cleanly restore the current directory with a `POPD`.

So, read `HELP PUSHD` and `HELP CALL` and try this.

```
pushd %MPWR_PATH%
for %%i in (*) do CALL :display %%i
popd
goto :eof

:display
echo %~f1
goto :eof
```